# How to convert an image from any web page to base64 string using grails?

Tags: java, grails

Here is code I tried but got image null:

```
  URL url = new URL("http://mobilecodec.alipaydev.com/show.htmcode=ocx057651zbaibcseqxe1b6");
    def image = ImageIO.read(url);
    final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try{
            ImageIO.write(image, 'png', os);
            println Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(os.toByteArray());
         }catch (final IOException ioe){
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
     }
```

Comment: Thank in advance!

Comment: your url seems to be invalid, it's missing a `?` after `.htm`

Comment: Ok very thanks ,pls try this url http://mobilecodec.alipaydev.com/show.htm?code=ocx069921seymdv02lsqzd0 instead.

Comment: If you can't find solution on groovy/grails, you can try to look solution on java: https://gist.github.com/utsengar/1276960/9e99b409e8d57c624e2a16793faa9c16e3745db2 here is a gist that should help you

Comment: Okay! Thank you sir.